# Django QuerySet last added from a category

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Probably an extremely easy solution, but cant really come up with one.
The end-goal is to create a gallery showing at first the categories. Each category should display the last added image with the respective category name.

My models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name           = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug           = models.SlugField()
    objects        = models.Manager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Item(models.Model):
    name           = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description    = models.TextField(blank=False, null=True)
    date           = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, null=True)
    image          = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    category       = models.ForeignKey(Category, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    objects        = models.Manager()


    class Meta:
        app_label = 'home'
        get_latest_by = 'date'
```

My views.py

```
def index(request):
    cat = Category.objects.all()
    latest = Item.objects.latest('date')

    context = {
        'categories': cat,
        'last_added': latest,
    }
    return render(request, 'gallery/index.html', context)
```

My index.html

```
{% block content %}
<h4 class="gallery">Gallery</h4>
    {% for category in categories %}
        <p class="category">{{ category.name }}</p>
        <p> <img class="images" src="{{ last_added.image.url }}"> </p>    
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

I cannot figure out how to display the latest image for their respective category. 
I know i have to somehow create a dynamic query that would use the 'category.name' as variable, but how do you do this?
Any input would be very valuable, at least indicating the direction in which i should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add in your view:

```
for c in cat:
    cat.latest_image = Item.objects.filter(category=c).latest('date')
```

and then in the relevant part of your your template:

```
<img class="images" src="{{ cat.latest_image.image.url }}">
```

That's just an example, there are tons of more elegant ways of achieving that.

Comment: Tried it but did not work, got the following error "int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'dict'"
Where exactly do you add the for loop in the view file? I am a complete novice in python. Really need some help with this, have been struggling for the past 2 days.

Comment: I edited the answer, try without `.values()`. This is not a python issue but the way Django works with Querysets and filters. Put that after the `cat` definition, instead of `latest`. You kind of add a temporary attribute to each cat object that you can use in your template.